# How to create a table that loops over data in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create a table that returns the top 10 aggregate `cons_name` over a given week, that repeats every day.

So for 5/29/2019 it will pull the top 10 `cons_name` by their sum dating back to 5/22/2019.

Then, for 5/28/2019, the top 10 `cons_name` by their sum back to 5/21/2019.

A table of top 10 dating back 7 days all the way to 2018-12-01.

I can make the simple code dating back 7 days but, I have tried Windows to no avail.

```
SELECT cons_name,
       pricedate,
       sum(shadow)
FROM spp.rtbinds
WHERE pricedate >= current_date - 7
GROUP BY cons_name, shadow, pricedate
ORDER BY shadow asc
LIMIT 10
```

This query generates the output below

```
cons_name       pricedate               sum
"TEMP17_24078"  "2019-05-28 00:00:00"   "-1473.29723333333"
"TEMP17_24078"  "2019-05-28 00:00:00"   "-1383.56638333333"
"TMP175_24736"  "2019-05-23 00:00:00"   "-1378.40504166667"
"TMP159_24149"  "2019-05-23 00:00:00"   "-1328.847675"
"TMP397_24836"  "2019-05-23 00:00:00"   "-1221.19560833333"
"TEMP17_24078"  "2019-05-28 00:00:00"   "-1214.9914"
"TMP175_24736"  "2019-05-23 00:00:00"   "-1123.83254166667"
"TEMP72_22893"  "2019-05-29 00:00:00"   "-1105.93840833333"
"TMP164_23704"  "2019-05-24 00:00:00"   "-1053.051375"
"TMP175_24736"  "2019-05-27 00:00:00"   "-1043.52104166667"
```

I would like a table and function that returns a table of each day's top 10 dating back a week.

Comment: Some sample data with expected output would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using window functions get's you on the right track but you should be reading further in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) about the possibilities.

We have multiple issues here that we need to solve:

1. gaps in the data (missing `pricedate`) not get us the correct number of rows (7) to calculate the overall sum
2. for the calculation itself we need all data rows so the `WHERE` clause cannot be used to limit only to the *visible* days
3. in order to select the top-10 for each day, we have to generate a row number per partition because the `LIMIT` clause cannot be applied per group

This is why I came up with the following CTE's:

1. CTE **days**: generate the gap-less date series and mark visible days
2. CTE **daily**: `LEFT JOIN` the data to the generated days and produce daily sums (and handle `NULL` entries)
3. CTE **calc**: produce the cumulative sums
4. CTE **numbered**: produce row numbers reset each day
5. select the actual visible rows and limit them to max. 10 per day

So for a specific week (2019-05-26 - 2019-06-01), the query will look like the following:

```sql
WITH
    days (c_day, c_visible, c_lookback) as (
        SELECT gen::date, (CASE WHEN gen::date < '2019-05-26' THEN false ELSE true END), gen::date - 6
        FROM generate_series('2019-05-26'::date - 6, '2019-06-01'::date, '1 day'::interval) AS gen
    ),
    daily (cons_name, pricedate, shadow_sum) AS (
        SELECT
            r.cons_name,
            r.pricedate::date,
            coalesce(sum(r.shadow), 0)
        FROM days
        LEFT JOIN spp.rtbinds AS r ON (r.pricedate::date = days.c_day)
        GROUP BY 1, 2
    ),
    calc (cons_name, pricedate, shadow_sum) AS (
        SELECT
            cons_name,
            pricedate,
            sum(shadow_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY cons_name ORDER BY pricedate ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        FROM daily
    ),
    numbered (cons_name, pricedate, shadow_sum, position) AS (
        SELECT
            calc.cons_name,
            calc.pricedate,
            calc.shadow_sum,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY calc.pricedate ORDER BY calc.shadow_sum DESC)
        FROM calc
    )
SELECT
    days.c_lookback,
    numbered.cons_name,
    numbered.shadow_sum
FROM numbered
INNER JOIN days ON (days.c_day = numbered.pricedate AND days.c_visible)
WHERE numbered.position < 11
ORDER BY numbered.pricedate DESC, numbered.shadow_sum DESC;
```

Online example with generated test data: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a83a52e33ffea3783207e6b403bc226a

Example output:

```
 c_lookback |  cons_name   |    shadow_sum    
------------+--------------+------------------
 2019-05-26 | TMP400_27000 | 4578.04474575352
 2019-05-26 | TMP700_25000 | 4366.56857151864
 2019-05-26 | TMP200_24000 | 3901.50325547671
 2019-05-26 | TMP400_24000 | 3849.39595793188
 2019-05-26 | TMP700_28000 | 3763.51693260809
 2019-05-26 | TMP600_26000 | 3751.72016620729
 2019-05-26 | TMP500_28000 | 3610.75970225036
 2019-05-26 | TMP300_26000 | 3598.36888491176
 2019-05-26 | TMP600_27000 | 3583.89777677553
 2019-05-26 | TMP300_21000 | 3556.60386707587
 2019-05-25 | TMP400_27000 | 4687.20302128047
 2019-05-25 | TMP200_24000 | 4453.61603102228
 2019-05-25 | TMP700_25000 | 4319.10566615313
 2019-05-25 | TMP400_24000 | 4039.01832416654
 2019-05-25 | TMP600_27000 | 3986.68667223025
 2019-05-25 | TMP600_26000 | 3879.92447655788
 2019-05-25 | TMP700_28000 | 3632.56970774056
 2019-05-25 | TMP800_25000 |  3604.1630071504
 2019-05-25 | TMP600_28000 | 3572.50801157858
 2019-05-25 | TMP500_27000 | 3536.57885829499
 2019-05-24 | TMP400_27000 | 5034.53660146287
 2019-05-24 | TMP200_24000 | 4646.08844632655
 2019-05-24 | TMP600_26000 |  4377.5741555281
 2019-05-24 | TMP700_25000 | 4321.11906399066
 2019-05-24 | TMP400_24000 | 4071.37184911687
 2019-05-24 | TMP600_25000 | 3795.00857752701
 2019-05-24 | TMP700_26000 |  3518.6449117614
 2019-05-24 | TMP600_24000 | 3368.15348120732
 2019-05-24 | TMP200_25000 | 3305.84444172308
 2019-05-24 | TMP500_28000 | 3162.57388606668
 2019-05-23 | TMP400_27000 | 4057.08620966971
 2019-05-23 | TMP700_26000 | 4024.11812392669
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this certainly helps. How do I run the query on a specific date? Say, "2019-02-07"

Comment: Provided a much better version of the query which allows you to just set the _from_ - _to_ dates in the first CTE and the rest is adapted automatically. For the single-day calculation just set all date constants to that date.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting an error ERROR:  column "r.pricedate" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 7:         SELECT r.cons_name, r.pricedate, sum(r.shadow)

Comment: Sorry, a type-o. Added the second column to the `GROUP BY' in CTE `daily`.

Comment: So what the code generates is great, but is there a way to make it loop over each day and make a list of the top 10 for each day and then create a column that is the 
7 day "lookback" date?  That make sense? So for what we have 2019-06-01 is the lookback date and any cons_name sum generated will have "2019-06-01" instead of the pricedate. And ontop of that make a list looping over from 2018-12-01. More curveballs I know!

Comment: Updated the query and also included a link to an online example where you can play around. To calculate things for a different range of days, just use different values (but don't modify the offsets/intervals) in the `days` CTE.

Comment: This worked! Thanks. Now, any tips on using Pandas to complete this?

Comment: Sorry, that's out of my expertise.